# How to correctly format JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, api

i'm attempting to create a RESTful API using PHP. I'm unable to format it in a way I'm used to seeing. Would appreciate some guidance. Thank.

This is the current JSON output:

```
 [
    {
        "boardID": "12345",
        "MQ9": "673627",
        "MQ131": "87565",
        "MQ135": "67887",
        "longitude": "51.504425",
        "latitude": "-0.1291608",
        "time": "13:32",
        "date": "2018-03-14"
    },
```

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
        "boardID": "12345",
        "MQ9": "673627",
        "MQ131": "87565",
        "MQ135": "67887",
        "longitude": "51.504425",
        "latitude": "-0.1291608",
        "time": "13:32",
        "date": "2018-03-14"
   },
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
  require 'connect.php';

  if(!$con){ 
  die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error()); 
  } 

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM airQual"); 

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
  { 
  $output[]=$row; 
  } 

  echo(json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); 

  mysqli_close($con);

  ?>
```

Comment: Try `$output["data"][] = $row;`.

Comment: Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the desired output as its first argument and `TRUE` as its second argument to get the array you need to obtain. Change your code to construct this array. Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and practice working with them.

Comment: you have 2 obvious syntax errors that I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this one of a couple of ways, but the easy way would be to do this, adding your output to another array:

```
$data = array('data' => $output);
echo(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

For example:

```
$output = array('foo'=>1,'bar'=>2,'glorp'=>3);
$data = array("data" => $output);
echo(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

returns

```
{
    "data": {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 2,
        "glorp": 3
    }
}
```

You can also add your output to another array, as others have suggested, this way:

```
$output['data'] = array('foo'=>1,'bar'=>2,'glorp'=>3);
echo(json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Which will give you the same return as above.

### NOTE

You have a typo in your code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) // missing closing )
```

`mysqli_error()` requires the connection:

```
 die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..  Am I correct I thinking that $data is an object and $output is an array!?  Please excuse my ignorance, I’m very new to this.

Comment: Both of those can be either. In your code `$output` is an array. In my example `$data` is also an array. You are only fetching an array from your database, so I only dealt with it as an array here.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!  And pointing me in the right direction! Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  require 'connect.php';

  if(!$con){ 
  die('Could not connect'); 
  } 

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM airQual"); 

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  { 
  $output['data'][]=$row; 
  } 

  echo(json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); 

  mysqli_close($con);

  ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

The output is correct, as you're creating an array. If you want an object, create an object!

Do something like;

```
$myOuput = new stdClass;
$myOuput->data = $output;
json_encode($myOutput);
```